# Sublime text is not highlighting Kivy .kv files

Tags: python, kivy, sublimetext, kivy-language

I am using Sublime Text editor. There, when I write Kivy's `.kv` file syntax, it does not highlight it.

There are my questions -

- Why it does not highlight?
- How do I make it highlight my syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Sublime provides syntax highlighting for several different types of files out of the box, and you can extend that by adding packages that provide extra syntax highlighting for file types that it doesn't directly ship with.

In addition, the association between the syntax highlighting used and the file itself is based on the extension on the file; syntaxes generally include a list of file extensions to which they apply.

So generally speaking, when using file types that don't have syntax highlighting, you need to determine what kind of file it is, and then either install a package that supports it, or give Sublime a hint that a syntax that it already knows about can be used for this type of file.

I'm not familiar with a `.kv` file, but based on your tags it would appear that it's something Python related. In that case, opening up a `.kv` file and then choosing `View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as...` and picking `Python` from the list will create an association that tells Sublime to use Python syntax highlighting for those kinds of files.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the helpful information that OdatNurd gave in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72398305/1426065), there is also a Kivy-specific syntax definition available via Package Control - [`Kivy Language`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Kivy%20Language). Install it as you would any other Package Control plugin, and when you open a `.kv` file, it should highlight it automatically. If it doesn't, keep the `.kv` file open and select **`View → Syntax → Open all with current extension as… → Kivy Language`**. It should open automatically from then on.